# Accessing directive from a different module

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, angular-directive, angular-controller

I have two different modules , first one contains controller second directive.

Basically i want the `directive` to be rendered in my `view`.
But as `modules` for `directive`and`controller` are different, its giving error.

If i give same `module` then it ressolves my issue by i want a generic module serving all controllers.

**`controller`**

```
angular.module('SlamModuleCtrl')
        .controller('SlambookExt',['$scope','$route','SlambookCollection', function($scope,$route) {
            console.log("slam controller")
        }]);
```

**`Directive`**

```
angular.module('Genericmodule')
    .directive('appVersion', ['version', function (version) {
       return {
    restrict: 'E',  
    template: '<h1>version1</h1>'
    } 
    }])
```

`View`

```
 <div ng-controller="SlambookExt">
     <app-version>1</app-version>
    </div>
```

Comment: what do you mean by injecting directive into controller? why don't put that controller inside your directive..

Comment: @PankajParkar basically i want to access directive that is different module,so somehow one has to inject that directive in the controller's module. And i cant put controller in directive as controller contains much more logic putting it in directive will amount to limiting its scope.

Comment: You need to [clear your basic first](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive), as you are asking for wrong thing to put directive inside controller..

Comment: @PankajParkar How do you integrate directive with a view ?
regrding this question tell me how can one access a directive in a different 
module ?

Comment: Just by adding the directive element on html, just readup on the provided link first that have all the things which you needed.

Comment: @PankajParkar
Till now whatever cases i have seen direve and controller are in same module so one can directly access but in my case they are in different modules?Can you throw some light on it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When instantiating `slamModuleCtrl`, you need to specify `genericModule` as a dependency.

Or use a parent module that loads both those modules as dependencies and use that parent module as your `ng-app`.

`angular.module('parentModule',['slamModuleCtrl','genericModue'])`

This is just a plausible solution because both your modules look right to me. So I'm guessing that the version is not showing up because the module hasn't been loaded

Answer (score 2):

Chanthu is correct you need to specify a parent module that has dependencies on your other modules but you also pass a array of dependencies for your other modules, in this case they don't have any.

declare your modules and add them in to the parent module like so...

```js
var controllerModule = angular.module('controllerModule', []);

var directiveModule = angular.module('directiveModule', []);


controllerModule.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
  $scope.hello = 'Hello';
})


directiveModule.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    template: '{{hello}}'
  };
});

angular.module('app', ['controllerModule', 'directiveModule']);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="mainController">

  <my-directive></my-directive>

</body>
```

code snippet shows another module directive and uses the binding from another module controller